# How to usb-connect multiple android devices with adb on windows 7

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to automate some of the test cases where in i need to connect to multiple devices , most of the time adb connects to only one device . For that every time i used to kill-server and start-server manually but when i execute adb devices command , its listing both of the devices . Can anyone tell me step by step how to usb connect multiple android devices with adb on windows 7 , so that i need not restart the adb server .

adb devices lists both the devices as below :

C:\Users>%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\adb devices

List of devices attached

0123456789ABCDEF        device

0123456789ABCD          device

adb rarely connects to both devices , how to make it connect to both the devices simultaneously

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use adb devices to get a list of connected devices and then run adb -s DEVICE_SERIAL_NUM install... for every device listed.

Something like (bash):
adb devices | tail -n +3 | cut -sf 1 -d " " | xargs -iX adb -s X install ...

Comments suggest this might work better for newer versions:
adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1 | xargs -iX adb -s X install ...

if you get any error then try this also adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1 | xargs -iX adb -s X install -r *.apk